# Почему не получается этот запрос?

Tags: sql-server, sql

В БД я добавил эту строку

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES(320,Иванов,карен 300,ереван,1991-05-25,40)
```

Почему не получается этот запрос?

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE SURNAME LIKE '%ов'
```

Comment: у меня Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: А вы уверен что вы добавил этот строка ?
что то я боюсь что оно не выполнятся без кавычка. убедится не мешать было бы..

Comment: да конечно зделаю етот запрос SELECT * FROM STUDENT и там есть етот строк.Но знаете когда зделая такой запрос SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE SURNAME LIKE 'Ив%' все получается.Короче знак %-а не могу поставить в начале и получить соответствующий резултат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE rtrim( cast( SURNAME as varchar ) ) LIKE '%ов'
```

Comment: да так получалось.А как понять етот, что зделал rtrim( cast( SURNAME as varchar ) ) ?????? И почему у меня получалос поставить % в канце,но вот в начале нет???

Comment: Строки сравниваются точно ( с учётом пробелов ) и:

Вероятно у данного столбца тип - CHAR ( что означает "строгую длинну" и дополнение до неё пробелами )..

Конструкция rtrim( cast( SURNAME as varchar ) ) как раз и убирает концевые пробелы...

P.S:

1. Если ответ решил вашу проблему - выберите его ( слева от ответа - галочка ).
2. Проголосуйте за все полезные ответы ( слева от ответа - пальчик вверх )

Comment: все понятно спасибо вам

Answer (score 1):

Есть подозрение, что вот эта строка ваабще не отработала

INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES(320,Иванов,карен 300,ереван,1991-05-25,40),

ибо, во-первых, значения заданы не верно, а, во-вторых, не мешало бы именовать столбцы, которые вы инициализируете данными (`INSERT STUDENT (id,FirstName,'')VALUES ('')`)

Answer (score -2):

Засунуть туда можно методом как сказал aachurin, а достать можно еще так:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE surname='Петров'");
```

Comment: и кто вам плючанул за такое? было же сказано, что у человека ``Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2`` какой ``mysql_query``?